# Создание зависимого select без привязки к модели на Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

В виджете ActiveForm при создании задачи(`offers`) предполагается, что будет исполнитель, за которым эта задача закрепляется. В таблице `offers` executor_responsible ссылается на таблицу users и берет оттуда id юзера. В таблице `users` также хранится department_id(название отдела) которое ссылается на поле id таблицы `departments` к которому принадлежит данный user.
Вот вьюха для Offers, а точнее искомое поле:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'executor_responsible')->dropDownList($items,$params) ?>
```

Мне нужно заблокировать выпадающий список для поля executor_responsible, и создать (непривязанный к $model) dropdownList, который хранит в себе id отделов, и по значению которого формируется и разблокируется dropdownList для 'executor_responsible'. Как это организовать ?

Comment: Пробовал создавать в модели Offers action для `departments` и `executor` и обращаться к ним через jquery, а они принимают id возвращают нужный title в зависимости от атрибута. Но и это не вышло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге создал в `OffersController` виртуальное поле `$executor_department`. В rules добавил его к 'safe' полям. В Active Form добавил `$executor_department`. Также воспользовался расширением `DepDrop` от kartik. Вот код формы offers/view/_form` :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'executor_department')->dropDownList($departments, [
    'id'=>'dep-id',
    'prompt'=> 'Выберите отдел'

]);
 ?>
  <?=$form->field($model, 'executor_responsible')->widget(DepDrop::classname(), [
    'options' => ['id'=>'exec-id'],
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'depends'=>['dep-id'],
        'placeholder' => 'Выберите...',
        'url' => Url::to(['offers/executor'])
    ]
]); ?>
```

Далее создал 2 метода в `OffersController`:

```
 private static function getExecutorsList($dep_id)
{
    $ex = Users::find()->select(['id', 'surname','name','patronymic'])->andWhere(['department_id' => $dep_id])->asArray()->all();
    $data['out'] = $ex;

    for ($i= 0; $i < count($ex);$i++) {
        $data['out'][$i]['name'] = $data['out'][$i]['surname']." ".iconv_substr($data['out'][$i]['name'],0,1,'UTF-8').".".iconv_substr($data['out'][$i]['patronymic'],0,1,'UTF-8');
    }

    $data['selected'] = $ex[0];
    return ($data);
}
  public function actionExecutor()
{
    $out = [];
    if (isset($_POST['depdrop_parents'])) {
        $ids = $_POST['depdrop_parents'];
        $dep_id = empty($ids[0]) ? null : $ids[0];
        // $subcat_id = empty($ids[1]) ? null : $ids[1];
        if ($dep_id != null) {
            $data = self::getExecutorsList($dep_id);


            echo Json::encode(['output' => $data['out'], 'selected' => $data['selected']]);
            return;
        }
    }
    echo Json::encode(['output' => '', 'selected' => '']);
}
```

Буду рад услышать пожелания, рекомендации, касательно кода